# Problem in opening downloaded application

Tags: macos

I downloaded an application from internet but it won't open even after I changed the system preferences. When i am trying to open the downloaded app it is saying that "This application can't be opened". How can I resolve this?

Comment: Some more details would make it easier to answer your question: Which application did you download and from where? Which System Preferences did you change? Can you please add a screenshot of the error message (or if possible the whole screen *with* the error message)?

Comment: So you changed the Security & Privacy to allow download from anywhere? and the app you downloaded is for a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I'll dare another stab in the dark, since the mentioned message comes close to what one sees in the following scenario (see screenshot).
If the application downloaded is not zipped, or packed into a dmg, etc., the executable might not have its executable bit set (or better can lose it).

One can then add the "x" (executable bit) by typing the following in Terminal (found in the 'Utilities' folder) with a space at the end and dragging the executable file onto the Terminal window to fill in the path to it, then hitting 'enter' (right click the application in question, select "Show Contents" and navigate to the folder "MacOS", where the executable lives in):

```
chmod oga+x
```

i.e. "change modification for owner, group and all, adding the executable bit"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the app and select Open. You'll then be given the option to open the app.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14369

Comment: how would that work for blocked app ?

Comment: That works for me

Comment: I shall try that, it is new to me !

Comment: I added a link to the Apple support article